# I get different results on different devices even though I'm using the dimensions of the screen

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I need to place the map exactly at a specific point of the screen and for that I use Positioned, I used Get.height and Get.with to have the same position on different devices, I have numbered them to fit where I want but still its position changes on different phones

```
 InteractiveViewer(
      maxScale: 3,
      child: Stack(children: [
        Positioned(right: Get.width / 1.875, top: Get.height / 5.263, 
            child: Text('here is the map widget')),
      ])),
```

Comment: You can use the package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil to set the positioning of your widget.

Comment: i tried a bit but i guess it didn't work or i am using the wrong thing